# whats is the best way of getting the name of the controller action that i am currently in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a number of asp.net-mvc controller actions that look like this:

```
 public ActionResult Home()
 {
      return View(new MyViewModel("Home"));
 } 

 public ActionResult Architecture()
 {
      return View(new MyViewModel("Architecture"));
 }
```

is there anyway to get the name of the method that i am in to avoid having to hard code the string "Home" or "Architecture" ??

Comment: Related/duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408743/asp-net-mvc-current-action-from-controller-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
var action = RouteData.Values["action"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at T4MVC. http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC

Comment: what particular about T2MVC helps my problem ?? I see how this can replace hard coded strings with something more appealing but it still seems like its a hard coded Template where i want it to dynamically figure out what the name of the current controller action is ?