# asp.net mvc - Check what controller and method are called?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, methods, controller

How to check what controller and method are called?

In html in body tag there is: `<body id="somethingThatDependsOnControllerAndMethod">`. `id` value will be assigned based on controller and it's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this in my MasterPage to get this info to display certain things on-screen, might help with the info you need (might not be the most elegant solution)

```
 public string ControllerActionName
        {
            get
            {
                return String.Concat(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"], ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"]).ToLower();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362514/asp-net-mvc-current-action/1408919#1408919).  It describes how to get the info you need within your controller and then you can pass that info down to your view using a view model or the ViewData property bag.

I prefer this method, because it gives my view everything it needs to do it's job.  I also don't like using the ViewContext, because it means I have to use strings to access it's dictionary for what I need and I prefer to keep everything strongly typed.