# Getting Action name in View (ASP.NET MVC2)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to get current action name in master page, so that i can find the "current" page link and mark it as "current".

Here is my view code snippet from Master Page:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="<%= Url.Action("Index", "Admin")%>" class="main current">Index</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="<%= Url.Action("Show", "Admin")%>" class="main">Show</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="<%= Url.Action("Delete", "Admin")%>" class="main">Delete</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, the Index hyperlink has a class of "current", which makes it highlighted via css files.

I want to check the Action that user is visiting, and make the hyperlink "current" with respect to that. I have searched through web, and wondering what is the best solution to that?

Also, I appreciate if you guys have any other suggestions about accomplishing this task.

Thanks in advance,
Sadullah

PS: Even though I found the solution, there must be a nicer way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Current Action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362514/asp-net-mvc-current-action)