# in asp.net-mvc, how can i build up URLs in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

if my current controller, my URL is:

```
 http://test.mysite.com/Person/Detail/1
```

how can i extract into a variable:

1. Full URL (http://test.mysite.com/Person/Detail/1)
2. Root url (http://test.mysite.com)

i am sending links inside of emails so i can't just use relative URLs (that why i need something that will get me these URLs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `var fullUrl = Request.RawUrl;`.
2. `var rootUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);`

Comment: full url just meant current url.  i had a typo

Comment: @ooo, then `Request.RawUrl` should give you this. I've updated my answer to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer it may be of use:

[How can I return the current action in an ASP.NET MVC view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362514/asp-net-mvc-current-action)

The [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) object is useful when working with URLs also