# How can I find out the controller and action name when in a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have decided to use a common viewModel for a number of my screens. However to add to my flexibility I would like to at least know the name of the controller and action that called the viewModel / view.

Is it possible to get this information and how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: I think this might answer your question..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362514/how-can-i-return-the-current-action-in-an-asp-net-mvc-view

Comment: I checked the link. Some of those posts look very old so I am wondering if there is a new way in MVC3?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any MVC3 specific ways of getting the date I would use the route data. like ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider["action"].RawValue
ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider["controller"].RawValue. - That's a lie.. I would actually look at passing that information to my view.. rather than my view working it out.. views are in my opinion just for displaying data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var action = (string)ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue;
var controller = (string)ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue;
```