# MVC4 - is there any way to get current - not malformed - route from view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

What I mean is - if user type something like:

```
Http://somepage.com/iNdex/sOmEaCtIoN
```

I would like to get **/Index/SomeAction** (or whatever it is called inside my controller). Since above URL is routed correctly by MVC engine, I guess there should be a way to do this.

EDIT:

I would like to get this in my View.

Edit 2:

I managed to solved my problem by passing type of the controller:

```
ViewContext.Controller.GetType()
```

and

```
Request.Url.AbsolutePath
```

to my method - and then using toLower() when searching for method match - still it would be better to simply get the name of controller and method that will be invoked by current request...

Comment: Where exactly do you want to get this? There are way of getting the controller and action names.

Comment: I would like to get this inside my view, I need this in order to pass it to my BreadCrumbs generator.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but inside your action method you can use Request.Url to access properties of the URL

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362514/how-can-i-return-the-current-action-in-an-asp-net-mvc-view).

Comment: @AndreiV:

I already tried that one - unfortunately it returns malformed URL... however now I started testing and it seem that simple ToLower() on method name should do the trick, since MVC can't see a difference between - for example: Index() and index() - I will investigate it further...

Comment: If you're trying to build links, then you can simply use `@Html.ActionLink`.

Comment: @AndreiV:

Thanks but that is not what I'm trying to do ;] anyway I solved my problem by passing controller name and Request.Url path to my method, and then using ToLower(), but I would still prefer to simply get proper controller name and method that will be called...

Comment: Following the conventions, the class of the controller would require a "Controller" at the end of what you get using `ViewContext`. If you really need to compile and call the actions just like a normal method, you could use reflection. There are plenty examples of SO of calling a method by its name, using reflections.

Answer (score 1):

Just for answer your question, you can directly access the route values in your view through ViewContext:

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] @*controller name*@
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] @*action name*@
```

So in your specific case you can do:

```
@string.Concat(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"], "/", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"])
```

However personally I will still prefer to get those necessary value in controller and pass them into view through viewmodel.

Comment: Unfortunately this will still give us malformed names, for my example it will return controller as "iNdex", and action as "sOmEaCtIoN". However, from what I can see - MVC engine works by ignoring action name letter size, so we cannot put "index()", and "INDEX()" in our controller since MVC cannot distinguish between the two. So I think the "solution" I posted is bearable, and I think You are correct as well - it could be better to pass controller and action name inside ViewBag in controller.